# English sentence hypenation

Tags: arrays, c, string

I am working on a program about hyphenation a word but i want to make it a sentence hyphenation the code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int isVowel(char);

int main() {
    char word[50] = "", wordHyp[100] = "";
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    printf("Enter a word for hyphenation:\n");
    fgets(word,sizeof(word),stdin);

    for (i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (wordHyp[i] == '\0') {
            wordHyp[i] = word[i];
            count += 1;
        } else {
            wordHyp[count] = word[i];
            count += 1;
        }
        if (isVowel(word[i]) == 1) {
            if (isVowel(word[i + 1]) == 1) {
                wordHyp[count] = '-';
                count += 1;
            } else if (isVowel(word[i + 2]) == 1) {
                wordHyp[count] = '-';
                count += 1;
            } else if (isVowel(word[i + 3]) == 1) {
                wordHyp[count] = word[i + 1];
                count += 1;
                wordHyp[count] = '-';
                count += 1;
                i++;
            } else if (isVowel(word[i + 4]) == 1) {
                wordHyp[count] = word[i + 1];
                wordHyp[count + 1] = word[i + 2];
                wordHyp[count + 2] = '-';
                count += 3;
                i += 2;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", wordHyp);
    return 0;
}


int isVowel(char c) {

    switch (c) {
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
            return 1;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

example input:

> american university

output:

> a-me-ri-can- u-ni-ver-sity

expected output:

> a-me-ri-can u-ni-ver-sity

Any help is appreciated thank you very much :D

Comment: What is your question about this task?

Comment: i want to make it as the expected output

Comment: your program does not produce `a-me-ri-can- u-ni-ver-sity` but only `a-me-ri-can` for the simple reason `scanf("%s", word);` stops on the space so reads `american` only

Comment: why `sity` must not be cut to have `si-ty`?

Comment: im sorry the scan f is changed to fgets(word,sizeof(word),stdin)

Comment: Your problem seems to be that you look up to four characters ahead without ensuring that what is in between is valid input. (Both space and the null terminator return 0 from `isVowel`. You could even read past the null terminator, which would be a problem is repeated reads don't clear the buffer past the terminaror.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I marked the changed lines in comments) :

```
int main() {
    char word[50] = "", wordHyp[100] = "";
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    printf("Enter a word for hyphenation:\n");
    fgets(word,sizeof(word),stdin);

    for (i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (wordHyp[i] == '\0') {
            wordHyp[i] = word[i];
            count += 1;
        } else {
            wordHyp[count] = word[i];
            count += 1;
        }
        if (isVowel(word[i])) {
            if (word[i+1] && isVowel(word[i + 1])) { //<==
                wordHyp[count] = '-';
                count += 1;
            } else if (word[i+2] && isVowel(word[i + 2]) && word[i + 1] != ' ') { //<==
                wordHyp[count] = '-';
                count += 1;
            } else if (word[i+3] && isVowel(word[i + 3]) && word[i + 2] != ' ') { //<==
                wordHyp[count] = word[i + 1];
                count += 1;
                wordHyp[count] = '-';
                count += 1;
                i++;
            } else if (word[i+4] && isVowel(word[i + 4]) && word[i + 3] != ' ') { //<==
                wordHyp[count] = word[i + 1];
                wordHyp[count + 1] = word[i + 2];
                wordHyp[count + 2] = '-';
                count += 3;
                i += 2;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", wordHyp);
    return 0;
}
```